# awk compare multiple parameters to variable

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to parse through some error apache logs for the past 24 hours and need to compare the combination of some positional parameters to another awk variable

```
awk -vCurDate=`$1 $2 $3` -vDateT=`date -d'now-24 hours' +[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S:%f %Y` ' { if (CurDate > vDate)  print $0 }' error_log
```

The start of the line in the log file looks like this:

```
[Sun Apr 19 03:20:14.381242 2017]
```

Error output I'm getting:

```
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

When I just try to print out the value of `CurDate` I'm not getting the expected results. It just spits out a bunch of empty lines. Is the way I'm declaring `curDate` allowed?

```
awk -vCurDate=`$1 $2 $3` -vDateT="`date -d'now-24 hours' +'[%a %b %d'`" ' { print CurDate}' error_log
```

Comment: extra quotes might help: `date -d'now-24 hours' +"[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S:%f %Y"`

Comment: It's balking about your date command, not your awk command or flags.

Comment: Yep nothing at all to do with awk.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking just `date`:

```
$ date -d'now-24 hours' +[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S:%f %Y]
date: extra operand ‘%b’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

The date parameter must be quoted as it contains spaces.

```
$ date -d'now-24 hours' +"[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S:%f %Y]"
[Wed Apr 19 22:04:40:%f 2017]
```

I am getting `%f` because it is not recognized in my version of `date`:

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.26
```

If I want to get microsecond precision I have to use `%6N` to round nanoseconds to microseconds:

```
$ date -d'now-24 hours' +"[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S:%6N %Y]"
[Wed Apr 19 22:06:34:346471 2017]
```

Attempt to pass the variable to `awk`:

```
$ awk -vCurDate=`$1 $2 $3` -vDateT=`date -d'now-24 hours' +'[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S:%6N %Y]'` ' { if (CurDate > vDate)  print $0 }' error_log 
awk: fatal: cannot open file `19' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

The output of `date` must also be quoted as it contains spaces as well.

```
$ awk -vCurDate=`$1 $2 $3` -vDateT="`date -d'now-24 hours' +'[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S:%6N %Y]'`" ' { if (CurDate > vDate)  print $0 }' error_log
```

---

EDIT: To retrieve all log messages from last 24 hours using `date` and `awk`, you can use this code.

```
awk -vCurDate="`date +'[[]%a %b %d ..:..:..[.]...... %Y[]]'`" \
    -vOldDate="`date -d'now-24 hours' +'[[]%a %b %d ..:..:..[.]...... %Y[]]'`" \
    -vOldTime="`date -d'now-24 hours' +'[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%6N'`" \
'{\
if (($0 ~ "^" CurDate) \
|| ( \
($0 ~ "^" OldDate) && ($0 > OldTime) \
)) { print } }' error_log
```

CurDate matches logs created today -- we want all logs from today.
OldDate matches logs from yesterday, with hours to minutes masked.
OldTime is time exactly 24 hours ago. We pick yesterday logs with higher time than this.

All this is needed because the timestamp format does not maintain lexicographical order -- Fri will always be less than Thu although the dates are in opposite order.

A more general solution (e.g. with parametrizable amount of hours) would require date conversion to e.g. seconds from epoch and then comparing this value.

Comment: Thanks, that got me past the date error. However, I'm still not getting any results back despite knowing a record exists in the file that I'm trying to match for. I'm trying now to just print the output of `CurDate` and it doesn't seem to be working. It just prints out a bunch of blank lines. Is the way I'm defining `CurDate` correct?

Comment: Please explain what is your awk script supposed to do, it is not clear at all from your question nor from the script itself. `$1 $2 $3` are values of parameters and they are blank unless it is in a script or a function.

Comment: I'm trying to get only the rows from my error log that happened in the last 24 hours and pipe the results out to a file.